# How to overload convert

Tags: type-conversion, julia, overloading

I have two types `A` and `B`. I have written `B(a::A)` and `convert(::Type{B}, a)`, but this does not immediately make `Array{B}(as::Array{A})` work. Must I write this method as well? According to 
[the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/conversion-and-promotion/index.html#Defining-New-Conversions-1), I would expect Julia would handle the rest for me.

```
struct A end
struct B end
B(a::A) = B();
convert(::Type{B}, a) = B(a);

# These work
B(A());
convert(B, A());

# This doesn't
Array{B}([A()]);
```

This is the error

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type A to an object of type B
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T}, !Matched::T) where T at essentials.jl:154
  B(::A) at /home/mvarble/test.jl:3
Stacktrace:
 [1] setindex!(::Array{B,1}, ::A, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:767
 [2] copyto! at ./abstractarray.jl:753 [inlined]
 [3] copyto! at ./abstractarray.jl:745 [inlined]
 [4] Type at ./array.jl:482 [inlined]
 [5] Array{B,N} where N(::Array{A,1}) at ./boot.jl:427
 [6] top-level scope at none:0
 [7] include at ./boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [8] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [9] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [10] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:267
 [11] _start() at ./client.jl:436
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a method to `convert` from Base, and not define a new `convert` function in the current module. Therefore you should write:

```
Base.convert(::Type{B}, a) = B(a)
```

or

```
import Base: convert
```

before defining `convert` as you did in your code.

Comment: Gosh, that makes so much sense! Thank you!